# Firebase-admin Appengine connection broken issue in python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database, python-requests, google-app-engine-python

I am using Google Appengine with python 2.7 standard environment and try to push data on Firebase Realtime database using firebase-admin.But I got following error when push or get data,is it authentication issue,how to resolve this issue?

```
('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(62 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(62 bytes read))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
        rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
```

Comment: any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: getting the same one